# Read properties file from classpath (non-maven)

Tags: java, classpath

When I try to run my jar from another directory it cannot see the "config" folder with the "url.properties" file in it.

Inside MyProperties class I have the following code, **which runs perfectly when run from the same dir**:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("./config/url.properties");
properties.load(new InputStreamReader(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
in.close();
```

The class that contains this code is in the following tree:

```
myproject\MyAppClass.class
myproject\data\MyProperties.class
```

It runs fine if I run this jar which contains the above piece of code by doing:

```
C:\myjarfolder\>java -jar myApp.jar
```

But it does not find "url.properties" inside "config" and returns a error if I do:

```
C:\>java -jar c:\myjarfolder\myApp.jar
```

Obviously it seems a classpath problem, so I try the following without success and return the same "file not found" error:

```
C:\> java -cp "c:\myjarfolder\*;c:\myjarfolder\config" myproject.MyAppClass
C:\> java -cp "c:\myjarfolder\*;c:\myjarfolder\config\" myproject.MyAppClass
C:\> java -cp "c:\myjarfolder\*;config" myproject.MyAppClass
C:\> java -cp "c:\myjarfolder\*;config\" myproject.MyAppClass
C:\> java -cp "c:\myjarfolder\*;\config\" myproject.MyAppClass
C:\> java -cp "c:\myjarfolder\*;c:\myjarfolder\config\url.properties" myproject.MyAppClass
```

And many other variants with and without quotes, all without success.

---

Then I thought it could be a loaded resources problem and tryed to change the InputStream(its in a static method):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(MyProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("./config/url.properties"));

and then

properties.load(MyProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/url.properties"));
```

This way it does not work even when running in the same folder.

---

I also tried to put the config folder in the class-path: inside manifest. Dind't worked.

---

I tried many things I found here on stack and none seems to work.

Is there a way to make the first option (without getresources) to run from another dir?

If I somehow make it load from getResource, will it run from another dir if I refer the class path?

Comment: Is the config folder also packed in your jar, along with your properties file? And how does your "myjarfolder" folder look like? Is the config folder inside of it? The main problem is, that the folder from where you execute the `java -jar` command is the root folder for the java process. You specified the path to your properties file relative to it (since it starts with a "."). Therefore it works when you run it from the one folder, but not from the other

Comment: *Of course* you can't see `./config` from another directory that doesn't contain it. If it's on the CLASSPATH you should be loading it as a resource, not trying to open it as a file. There mightn't even be a file: it might be in a JAR or WAR or EAR.

Comment: @Sebsen36 This was the temp solution I had. I added the config folder as a source and compiled it inside the jar, then I could use the getResources and could run the -jar from another folder normally. The problem is that if I need to changed some of the config files, I have to open the jar and alter the configs inside.

Comment: @user207421 yeah. Is there a way to add it to classpath from java and then load it as resource? Or it has to be from windows environment tables (because I tried that also)? And why the -cp did not worked?

Comment: @user207421 nvm! I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When using absolute locations like FileInputStream("./config/url.properties"):**

Add the config folder inside the jar. From the IDE you can add it as a source and it will compile the folder inside the jar automatically. Then it can be run with "java -jar c:\myjarfolder\myJar.jar" from another folder no problem.

---

**When using getResources("url.properties"):**

Can't use the absolute location here or it will be the same problem as before, so to let the folder outside the jar and add it to the classpath (you may not run it from the IDE if not added to the run parameters classpath or the manifest).
The folder can be added by running it like:
'java -cp "c:\myjarfolder*;c:\myjarfolder\config" myproject.MyAppClass'

Also, it can be added to the MANIFEST.MF class-path, as example "class-path: config/".
(it only worked here with "/") and can be run with "java -jar c:\myjarfolder\myJar.jar".

---

I don't think this is a normal issue people will encounter because normaly you run the jar from the same location it is. But we were creating a RDP to run from server where it can't run the jar it self, but using the java.exe.